# How to send value of a checkbox using Formik

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, formik

I am making a formik form and every field sets and sends values correctly except my checkbox field.  I can't really find good documentation on it so was wondering if anyone could help me.

My props to values formik function:

```
  mapPropsToValues: props => ({
    firstName: props.firstName || '',
    lastName: props.lastName || '',
    businessName: props.businessName || '',
    email: props.email || '',
    phone: props.phone || '',
    zipCode: props.zipCode || '',
    yearsInBusiness: props.yearsInBusiness || '',
    callBackTime: props.callBackTime || '',
    paymentServices: [],
    paymentProcessing: props.paymentProcessing || ''
  }),
```

And my input field.

```
 <CheckboxField
   type="checkbox"
   name="paymentProcessing"
   value={values.paymentProcessing}
   label="Payment Processing Equipment"
  />
```

I basically need the value of the checkbox field to equal to label if checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your values prop in `<CheckboxField />`, but natively input’s use `event.target.checked` when the correct `type` is added.

Try checking what value prop appears in the component, also if your props for `paymentProcessing`, is not present you are sending a string:

```
paymentProcessing: props.paymentProcessing || ''
```

I would check values in the checkbox component and return undefined if there is no Boolean from paymentProcessing prop.

So you will not need an empty string above either, remember your are not dealing with a string with checkboxes.